# Pre-Calculus Domain & Discontinuity

Tags: algebra-precalculus, area

I'm doing some corrections on a test and this question has me stumped:

David wants to create a rectangular holding area for his baby dragons, but **only has 100 feet of fencing**. He is going to **use the backside of the school stadium for one side of the pen**, that way he only has to use the fencing on three sides and he can have a larger area for the young dragons. This distance from the school will also prevent the school from catching on fire.

a) If ***w*** represents the width of the pen, express its area ***A*** in terms of ***w***(the side of the stadium is the length).

b)What is the domain of the function ***A*** (determined by the physical restrictions)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I will give you hints because this problem looks like homework.

a) $A = w \times l$ where $l$ is the length of the pen. $l$ is the dimension along the stadium so the fence need only cover one side of length $l$. However, the fence must cover both sides of length $w$. We have a total of 100 feet of fencing. Can you express $l$ in terms of $w$ using the above facts? Then you can substitute this expression for $l$ in $A = w \times l$.

b) $A$ is a function of $w$. What values can $w$ take? The minimum possible width is when all the fence is along the length dimension and the maximum possible width is when all the fence is along the width dimension.